# Easiest way to insert LaTeX matrix?

Tags: autocompletion, plugin-system, plugin-vim-latex, snippets

Recently I found myself in a situation that need to type in quite a number of matrices to LaTeX by hand, so I was wondering if there are some tools that can help me to save some keystrokes.

The desired tool would work as follows. Whenever I need to insert a matrix, I trigger the plugin, then it prompts to ask me about the dimension of the matrix (for example, 4 by 3). Then it generates the following template:

```
\begin{bmatrix}
<++> & <++> & <++>\\
<++> & <++> & <++>\\
<++> & <++> & <++>\\
<++> & <++> & <++>\\
\end{bmatrix}<++>
```

I am following the LaTeX-suite convention here, but the actual format doesn't really matter.

Are there such tools? If not, I'd be very interested in *implementing* one myself, so are there any tools that have a similar function that I can refer to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could probably implement this as a snippet by leveraging [Ultisnips'](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) [Interpolation](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips/blob/aec91caefec10741722927cf073703a528fe7a8f/doc/UltiSnips.txt#L820) feature ([VimCasts demo](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/ultisnips-python-interpolation/)). As an alternative, I whipped up a simplistic function to generate a matrix template on the current line per your sample:

```
function! CreateMatrix(rows, ...) abort
  let cols = a:0 ? a:1 : 3
  let matrix = ['\begin{bmatrix}']
  call extend(matrix, repeat([repeat('<++> & ', cols - 1) . '<++>\\'], a:rows))
  call add(matrix, '\end{bmatrix}<++>')
  call append(line('.') - 1, matrix)
endfunction
command! -nargs=+ Matrix silent call CreateMatrix(<f-args>)
```

The provided command takes as arguments **rows** and optionally **columns**. If columns is left unspecified, it defaults to 3. For example, calling `:Matrix 3` would add the following to the current buffer:

```
\begin{bmatrix}
<++> & <++> & <++>\\
<++> & <++> & <++>\\
<++> & <++> & <++>\\
\end{bmatrix}<++>
```

Invoking `:Matrix 5 8` would add:

```
\begin{bmatrix}
<++> & <++> & <++> & <++> & <++> & <++> & <++> & <++>\\
<++> & <++> & <++> & <++> & <++> & <++> & <++> & <++>\\
<++> & <++> & <++> & <++> & <++> & <++> & <++> & <++>\\
<++> & <++> & <++> & <++> & <++> & <++> & <++> & <++>\\
<++> & <++> & <++> & <++> & <++> & <++> & <++> & <++>\\
\end{bmatrix}<++>
```

It should be easy enough to modify the function and/or command to your liking.

Comment: Thanks for both the function and the recommendation of ultisnips!

Comment: Excellent!.  I would include saving your cursor position to return to the top of the matrix, to start editing....

Answer (score 10):

### Honza's UltiSnips Snippet `gentbl<number>x<number>`

available in the repository https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets/blob/master/UltiSnips/tex.snippets

Using this snippet which uses the python interpolation feature of UltiSnips, you can enter e.g.

```
gentbl5x3<tab>
```

which will expand to

```
\begin{tabular}{||||}
   &  &  \\
   &  &  \\
   &  &  \\
   &  &  \\
   &  &  \\
\end{tabular}
```

Note the jump marks of UltiSnips are not visible.

For a possibility to adapt this for matrix environments, see the update of this answer.

Additionally rows can be added afterwards with the snippet `tr<number><tab>`. Having three columns you would enter

```
tr3<tab>
```

to get

```
 &  &  \\
```

### Update due to request in comment

```python
global !p
def create_matrix(snip):

        matrix_str = (snip.buffer[snip.line].split('mat')[0]+'matrix').strip()

        rows = 'x'.join(snip.buffer[snip.line].split("x", 2)[:-1])
        cols = 'x'.join(snip.buffer[snip.line].split("x", 2)[-1:])

        int_val = lambda string: int(''.join(s for s in string if s.isdigit()))

        rows = int_val(rows)
        cols = int_val(cols)

        offset = cols + 1
        old_spacing = snip.buffer[snip.line][:snip.buffer[snip.line].rfind('\t') + 1]

        snip.buffer[snip.line] = ''

        final_str = old_spacing + "\\begin{"+matrix_str+"}\n"
        for i in range(rows):
                final_str += old_spacing + '\t'
                final_str += " & ".join(['$' + str(i * cols + j + offset) for j in range(cols)])

                final_str += " \\\\\\\n"

        final_str += old_spacing + "\\end{"+matrix_str+"}\n$0"

        snip.expand_anon(final_str)
endglobal

pre_expand "create_matrix(snip)"
snippet "(small|[bBpvV])?mat(rix)?(\d+)x(\d+)" "Generate (small|[bBpvV])?matrix of *rows* by *columns*" br
endsnippet
```

This adds following snippet variants

```
matrix<N>x<M><Tab>
bmatrix<N>x<M><Tab>
Bmatrix<N>x<M><Tab>
pmatrix<N>x<M><Tab>
vmatrix<N>x<M><Tab>
Vmatrix<N>x<M><Tab>
smallmatrix<N>x<M><Tab>
```

Additionally, all of them can be shortened by replacing `matrix` with `mat`, e.g.

```
bmat4x3<Tab>
```

which will give you

```
\begin{bmatrix}
   &  &  \\
   &  &  \\
   &  &  \\
   &  &  \\
\end{bmatrix}
```

**LuaSnip**

for a [LuaSnip](https://github.com/L3MON4D3/LuaSnip) version you can find a definition here:

https://github.com/evesdropper/luasnip-latex-snippets.nvim

Comment: Could you may be elaborate more on how to achieve this in the bmatrix environment? Thank you!

Comment: See update of answer. I hope it helps.