# inoremap inserts unwanted tabs

Tags: key-bindings, indentation, filetype-tex, snippets

I recently made myself custom insert mode keybindings to type faster in LaTeX. However, When I use them, Vim adds tabs that weren't part of the original keybinding.

**Example:**

Here is my `inoremap`:

`autocmd FileType tex inoremap ;t \begin{table}<Enter>\caption{}<Enter>\label{<++>}<Enter>\begin{center}<Enter>\begin{tabular}{<++>}<Enter>\toprule<Enter><++><Space>\\<Enter>\toprule<Enter><++><Space>\\<Enter><++><Space>\\<Enter>\bottomrule<Enter>\end{tabular}<Enter>\end{center}<Enter>\end{table}<Enter><Enter><++><Esc>?caption{<Enter>8li`

This is the output (`<X>` is the final location of my cursor):

```
             \begin{table}
             \caption{<X>}
             \label{<++>}
             \begin{center}
             \begin{tabular}{<++>}
             \toprule
 <++> \\
             \toprule
 <++> \\
 <++> \\
             \bottomrule
             \end{tabular}
             \end{center}
             \end{table}

 <++>
```

Why isn't everything lining up at the beginning of the line? (the previous lines are not indented)

Thanks!

**P.S.**

I know that it would be more appropriate to use functions instead of mapping but I haven't learned them yet...

Comment: Id bet $$$ it’s a weird interaction with auto/smart/cindent if any of those are set.

Comment: I added your snippet to my vimrc and I cannot confirm your observation. Debug with an empty vimrc except your snippet. It looks like you are using vim-latex: `<++>` are the jump markers used by vim-latex. Vim-latex provides a different mechanism for template expansion: https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex/blob/master/plugin/imaps.vim#L5-L83 and http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/latex-macros.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Snippet plugin instead of a simple `inoremap`

If you are interested in features like jumping from one placeholder to another one, you might be interested in using a plugin.
There are many options you can choose from. There are a few dedicated to LaTeX:

1. [**vim-latex**](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex) (details in section [3.12](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/documentation/latex-suite/ls-new-macros.html) and [`plugin/imaps.vim`](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex/blob/master/plugin/imaps.vim))

   You can also install only `plugin/imaps.vim` with
   `$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vim-latex/vim-latex/master/plugin/imaps.vim -O ~/.vim/plugin/imaps.vim`
   and then define in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim`:

   ```
   call IMAP('ETE', "\\begin{table}\<CR>\\caption{<++>}\<CR>\\label{<++>}\<CR>\\begin{center}\<CR>\\begin{tabular}{<++>}\<CR>\\toprule\<CR><++><Space>\\\\\<CR>\\toprule\<CR><++><Space>\\\\\<CR><++><Space>\\\\\<CR>\\bottomrule\<CR>\\end{tabular}\<CR>\\end{center}\<CR>\\end{table}\<CR>\<CR><++>", 'tex')
   ```
2. [latex-support](https://wolfgangmehner.github.io/vim-plugins/latexsupport.html)
3. [quicktex](https://github.com/brennier/quicktex)

There are also a few plugins which provide a fixed set of snippets for LaTeX (however, you can always modify the source code):

1. [auctex.vim](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=162)
2. [drcstubs](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1269)
3. [texmaps](http://www.drchip.org/astronaut/vim/index.html#TEXMAPS)

I personally prefer a general plugin such as

1. [**Ultisnips**](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips)
2. [**snipmate**](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate)
3. [**neosnippet**](https://github.com/Shougo/neosnippet.vim)

Your insert mode mapping as a ultisnips snippet (e.g. placed in `~/.vim/UltiSnips/tex.snippets`):

```
snippet table "Table & Tabular"
\begin{table}
  \caption{${1:<+Caption text+>}}
  \label{tab:${2:<+label+>}}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{${3:<+dimensions+>}}
    \toprule
    $4 \\
    \toprule
    ${5:${VISUAL}} \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}$0
endsnippet
```

A more advanced snippet request is the question [Easiest way to insert LaTeX matrix?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/17439/easiest-way-to-insert-latex-matrix).

You find also similar ones predefined in snippet collections such as

- [honza/vim-snippets/UltiSnips/tex.snippets](https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets/blob/87dd0531825ad90539a49d3e73e44f90fcb5a0f7/UltiSnips/tex.snippets#L73-L82)
- [Shougo/neosnippet-snippets/neosnippets/tex.snip](https://github.com/Shougo/neosnippet-snippets/blob/3169f157e76f1140790721604658f031f9283741/neosnippets/tex.snip#L108-L117)

The question [What is the difference between the vim snippets plugins?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/7466/what-is-the-difference-between-the-vim-snippets-plugins) could also be interesting to compare the different options.